# Symfony Form fields manipulation

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am learning to work with symfony and all looks very great but I need to make some custom forms and I dont know how to procced with my case.

Is there a way to build dynamic forms based on xml definition files like on Magento? What I want to achieve is build forms that will have key - value storage in database with custom custom input type decided at the time when the form is build but as a presentation for users/admins I want to be structured on areas -> sections.

Is there a possibility to make this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can build all you need with symfony but don't exist a built in solution. PS: Please, read the StackOverflow's guidelines like: [What topics can I ask on StackOverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [Form Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html) does not provide this functionality.
But you can implement it youself or use third-party bundles.

The `FormBuilderInterface` is a nice declarative API for [form generation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).
You can define your own configuration format and use it to build a forms.

For example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use DOMDocument;

class XmlBasedFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Better if the format will be as similar to the  FormBuilder options:
        $formConfig = DOMDocument::loadXML(<<<'XML'
            <form>
                <field name="foo" type="text" label="Foo"/>
                <field name="bar" type="textarea" label="Bar"/>
                <field name="baz" type="checkbox" label="Baz"/>
            </form>
XML
        );

        foreach ($formConfig->getElementsByTagName('field') as $fieldElement) {
            $name = $fieldElement->getAttribute('name');
            $type = $fieldElement->getAttribute('type');
            $label = $fieldElement->getAttribute('label');

            // Build a form element:
            $builder->add($name, $type, ['label' => $label]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the [Config Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config.html) may be useful in this case.

But the full implementation of all form features may require *a lot of work*. Сonsider using a third-party solutions, such as [**Dynamic Form Bundle**](https://packagist.org/packages/linio/dynamic-form-bundle). That bundle generates Symfony forms by YAML configuration files. (I have some experience with this solution and it works well.)

Comment: That sounds wonderful. You my friend guided me to a much clearer path. I had such a complex solution now in my head but you showed me a simple path. Kudos to you.

Comment: I am glad to help. But the forms are really a complicated things and attempts to describe them completely declaratively are always difficult.

Comment: I will try my best with what I need and based on what you told me. Basically I want to build a configuration area like magento style because I am not very sure if in the future if I will add more config keys and I do really think that with xml definitions for inputs in forms are the best way ( even if it will be a bit of a pain )